# ajax запрос в бд

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

пользователь должен выбрать свой пол и потом это отправляется в базу

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы отправлялся один из двух выбранных вариантов

```
    <label for="male1">Mr</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="sendMale" value="MR" checked="checked">
    <label for="female">Mrs</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="sendFemale" value="MRS">
    <input type="submit" value="send" id="send">

$gender= $_REQUEST['gender'];
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO tickets (`gender`, ...) VALUES ('$gender',...)";
    $insert= mysql_query($insert_sql);

$("#send").click(function () {
     var myData = //"mail=" + $("#sendMail").val() + что-то вроде "&gender=" + $("#sendMale").val(); 

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../php/insert.php", 
        dataType:"text", 
        data:myData, 
        success:function(response){ //дальше неважно что   }); 
});
```

Comment: Приведи php скрипт обработчика. Либо попробуй сделать сам а потом приведи если что то не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну да, клиентская часть может быть, к примеру такой (обращаться по имени, и использовать json формат для передачи данных)

```
<label for="male1">Mr</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="sendMale" value="MR" checked="checked">
<label for="female">Mrs</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="sendFemale" value="MRS">
<input type="submit" value="send" id="send">

$("#send").click(function () {
    var gender = $('[name="gender"]:checked').val();
    var myData = {gender: gender};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../php/insert.php", 
        dataType: "json", 
        data: myData, 
        success: function(response) {
          //дальше неважно что   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: есть одно большое НО. 
мне нужно, чтобы выглядел var myData как-то так: 

var myData = "first="+ $("#sendFirst").val() + "&last=" + $("#sendLast").val()

Comment: Если именно в формате text, тогда просто подставляем значение name в `var myData = "mail=" + $("#sendMail").val() + "&gender="+ $('[name="gender"]:checked').val();`

Comment: @Daniel-664 спасибо огромное! сработало)

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь)

Comment: не подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать без использования var myData? то есть чтобы сразу записать в data как-то так : { 'first': $('#sendFirst').val(), }

Comment: Тот же принцип
`{gender: $('[name="gender"]:checked').val()}`

Comment: забыл упомянуть, что у меня уже не radio, а select. пытался сделать по этому же принципу, но не получается

Comment: `<select id="gender">
  <option value="MR">Mr</option>
  <option value="MRS">Mrs</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="send" id="send">

$("#send").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../php/insert.php", 
        dataType: "json", 
        data: {gender: $('#gender :selected').val()}, 
        success: function(response) {
          //дальше неважно что   
        }
    });
});`

Comment: уже пробовал так, но не получается

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
if (selected.length > 0){
   myData = selected.val();
}
```

Comment: хмм, не получается